# Weird behavior in BindingUtils.bindProperty: non deterministic

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, binding, flex4

I'm going slightly mad.

I'm having weird problems with `BindingUtils.bindSetter` and `bindProperty`. I thought that, if I'd bind two variables with `BindingUtils.bindProperty` I could be sure they would always be synchronized. But it's not so.

I have this code in a creationCompleteHandler:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "pendingHold", drhHold, "pending", false, true);
```

But when I debug, the two variables that should be bound together at some point have different values:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Nuno

Comment: Actually, I decided to use bindProperty because somehow bindSetter wasn't working properly either. It was invoking the setter only sometimes... I'm clueless...

Answer (score 1):

The binding you defined is one-way.  When `drhHold.pending` is set, then `this.pendingHold` will get set.  This does not go the other way around.

In other words, what you are describing can happen if you have the following code:

```
this.drhHold.pending = false;
this.pendingHold = true;
```

If you want this to go both ways, then you need to set up the other direction:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "pendingHold", drhHold, "pending", false, true);
BindingUtils.bindProperty(drhHold, "pending", this, "pendingHold", false, true);
```

All of this, of course, assumes that both of these properties are `[Bindable]`.

Comment: I understand. But I don't want it to go both ways. It just goes one way and it doesn't work anyway. "pendingHold" is just a wrapper so that I can expose "drhHold.pending" without exposing "drhHold". Thanks.

Comment: so what happened here was: they were both `true`. `drhHold.pending` became `false` but `pendinhHold` didn't change and remained `true`.

Comment: Ok.  It was worth a shot.  There wasn't enough info in the question to discern that.  Hmmmm... Are you sure something else isn't setting `this.pendingHold` back to `true` some place?  Have you put break points on the variables themselves to see when the getters/setters get called?  This would drive me mad as well... I guess the next step I'd try is to wire up the binding myself (hook the change event on `drhHold` and set `pendingHold` by hand) to see if I can learn anything from that.

Comment: Hi, I did put breakpoints in the setters and they aren't triggered properly. It did drove me crazy. After two nights fighting with this I decided to abandon BindingUtils altogether and replace them with events managed by me. And now it works fine. I'm not saying I didn't do something wrong, but I didn't understand what. Anyway, I moved on. But it's scary and confusing anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @nununo, if all you want to do is have a wrapper exposing drhHold.pending without exposing drhHold, why not just use a bindable getter?!

Comment: @J_A_X, that seems very reasonable.  He'll have to propagate the change notification, but that shouldn't be too bad since he is already hooking the events by hand.

Comment: @Brian, Actually, you don't have to do the change propogation notification *unless* the drhHold object changes within the class.  If it's just the boolean, he'll be fine because whoever is binding to it is listening to the boolean directly in drhHold.

Comment: hum... I'm confused. I have a bindable boolean `drhHold.pending` and a bindable `this.pendingHold`. But how can I make the latter change when the other changes without manually doing it with events? I don't get it. Can you write an answer with the example?

Comment: My solution was: `drhHold` doesn't have `pending` anymore. Now it dispatches an event called `pendingChanged` which contains pending's value. I listen to the event in `this`, `this.pending` has a public getter and private setter which I use to set `this.pending` value in in `this.pendingChangedHandler`. And works fine :)

Comment: @J_A_X can you please explain exactly what you mean with "whoever is binding to it is listening to the boolean directly in drhHold"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Binding isn't needed in this case:

```
public class Class1
{
   private var _class2:Class2 = new Class2();

   [Bindable]
   public function get pending():Boolean
   {
      return this._class2.pending;
   }

   public function set pending(value:Boolean):void
   {
      this._class2.pending = value;
   }
}
```

As long as Class2.pending is bindable as well, this will make it so that Class1.pending is binded to Class2.pending.

Comment: Have you tried this?  I tried this and a change to `_class2.pending` did not cause a change notification to `class1.pending`.  And Yes, `_class2.pending` is bindable... the view in my example is binding to both.  See http://pastie.org/2045521 and http://pastie.org/2045526